# MPLab Interrupt in Assembly Language

Tags: assembly, interrupt, mplab

Assembly code interrupt in MPlab

MPLAB IDE: v8.92
CHIP:      dsPIC33FJ64GP802

I've been going over this code for an interrupt in assembly language. I'm not sure if there is a problem with the code or the linker files (I've used the linker and header files  for the chip) but when I fire Asynchronous toggle INT0, the code encounters

```
 CORE-W0008: Software Reset Instruction called at PC=0x000202
```

and the code continues from the first line instead of going to the interrupt subroutine.
My research has not turned up many useful results for this software reset instruction.

Here is the code;

```
.include "p33FJ64GP802.inc" 

.global __reset 
.global __INT0interrupt         ; ISR (Interrupt Service Routine)   

.text                           

__reset:                ; Code section

MOV #0x900, W15                 ; Enable the stack register

MOV #__SPLIM_init, W0           

MOV W0, SPLIM                   ; Initialize Stack Pointer Limit Register

NOP 


CALL INITinit           ; Initialize interrupt enables

CALL initIO             ; Initialize interrupt I/O ports

CALL LED1


INITinit:               ; Initialize the interrupt

BSET IPC0, #0                   ; Set Interrupt Priority Control bit #0 high

BSET IPC0, #1                   ;  "      "         "       "    bit #1 high

BSET IPC0, #2                   ;  "      "         "       "    bit #2 high 
(interrupt has highest priority)

BSET IEC0, #0                   ; Set Interrupt Enable Control (Register 0) High 
(Interrupt request enabled) 

BCLR IFS0, #0                   ; Clear Interrupt Flag Status  (Register 0) Low

RETURN


initIO:                 ; Initialize Input/Output

MOV #0XFFFF, W0

MOV W0, AD1PCFGL                ; Disable analog I/O

MOV #0x0000, W0                 

MOV W0, TRISB                   ; Output direction

NOP

BCLR TRISB, #1                  ; Bit #1 cleared 'low' in TRISB     | Pin RB1 is 
output for LED1

NOP

BCLR TRISB, #2                  ; Bit #2 cleared 'low' in TRISB     | Pin RB2 is 
output  for LED2

NOP

BSET TRISB, #7                  ; Bit #7   set  'high' in TRISB     | Pin RB7 is 
input  for interupt

NOP

RETURN                          


LED1:                   ; Start of function 'LED 1'                 

MOV #0xFFFF, W1                 ; Blue LED 1 On 

MOV W1, PORTB                   

CALL DELAY                      

MOV #0x0000, W1                 ; Blue LED 1 Off

MOV W1, PORTB                   

CALL DELAY                                                      

GOTO LED1                       ; Go to LED1


DELAY:                  ; Start function delay

MOV #0x0001, W2                 ; Set W2 High

MOV #0x0000, W3                 ; Start W3 Low

again0:                         ; Function 'again1'

ADD #0x0001, W3                 ; Add value '1' to regiter 3

CPSEQ W3, W2                    ; Compare W3 to W2- if equal then skip next line

goto again0                     ; Go to again1

RETURN                          ; Return from subroutine


__INT0interrupt:            ; ISR           

NOP                             ; No operation

BTG PORTB, #7                   ; BIT #7 of Port B is toggled(complimented)

MOV #0x0005, W4

MOV #0X0000, W5

again1:

MOV #0XFFFF, W1

MOV W1, PORTB                   ; Red LED 2 On

CALL DELAY

MOV #0X0000, W1

MOV W1, PORTB                   ; Red LED 2 OFF

CALL DELAY

INC W5, W5

CPSEQ W4, W5

goto again1

BCLR IFS0, #0                   ; BIT #0 of the IFSO is cleared

NOP

RETFIE                          ; Return from interupt enable


.end
```

If anyone knew how to send the program counter to enter the interrupt service routine it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with this type of formatting when using ASM or with 16bit processor so I can't really distinguish everything that is happening there or guarantee a clear solution. However from my general ASM programming experience I know you must have a RESET vector and an Interrupt vector associated to the labels.

```
ORG 0x000
<reset vector>
ORG 0x14
<INT0Interrupt>
```

Did you have a look at this pdf showing the Interrupt table for your microprocessor family? INT0 Interrupt vector is located at address 0x14, normally unless you have code there your program will continue executing instructions outside or normal program execution, leading to erratic behavior.

http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70189C.pdf

The fact that you get a reset instruction at 0x202 is a clue because the Interrupt tablet ends at 0x200. 
I have always used ORG assembly directives to make sure the code is where it should be, try organising your code like this:

```
   ORG 0x000
   goto program_entry_point
   ORG 0x014
   goto INT0Interrupt

   ORG 0x200
program_entry_point
   <device initialization code>
main_program_loop
   <your code here>
   goto main_program_loop

   ORG 0x400
INT0Interrupt
   <ISR Code>
   RETFIE

   end
```